# ローカルにある branch を GitHub に push したい

Tags: git, github

リモートにローカルブランチごと(feat/knockout)をpushしたいのですが、可能でしょうか？
やり方を教えてください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

pushコマンドの理解は以下で正しいですか？

```
$ git push origin master (ローカルのmasterをリモートのorigin/master)
$ git push origin feat/knockout(ローカルのmasterをリモートのorigin/ feat/knockout)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2):

ローカルで`feat/knocout`ブランチにチェックアウトした状態で、以下のコマンドを実行してください。

```
$ git push -u origin feat/knocout
```

`-u origin`はどのリモートリポジトリを追跡対象にするか指定するオプションで、自分が管理しているリポジトリであれば通常は`origin`を指定します。このオプションで設定しておくことで、次回以降の指定を省略することができます(`git push`だけでpushできる)。

P.S.
「ノックアウト」の綴りは正しくは「knoc**k**out」ですね。もしブランチ名を修正する場合はいったん別のブランチにチェックアウトした状態で

```
$ git checkout master
$ git branch -m knocout knockout
```

Comment: この場合
originはcheckoutしている、矢印が向いているローカルブランチという理解で大丈夫ですよね？

Comment: originはリモートリポジトリの名前です。矢印が何を指しているのか分からないので質問文に追記してもらうか、私が回答したコマンドの前後で`git branch -a -vv`を実行してみてください。

Comment: 確認結果は私の回答を編集するのではなく、ご自身の質問文の方を編集してください。